# JBoss 7.1.1 Clustering, JBAS014775:New missing/unsatisfied dependencies

Tags: java, cluster, jboss

I am following https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/AS7+Cluster+Howto

I managed to get 2 servers running.
One slave.
One master.

I managed to get to "Dry Run"
I got:

```
[Host Controller] 11:30:58,636 INFO  [org.jboss.as.domain] (domain-mgmt-handler-thread - 1) JBAS010918: Registered remote slave host "slave", JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes"
```

But when I try to start server-three, I got this error:

```
[Host Controller] 12:01:08,499 INFO  [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (HttpManagementService-threads - 11) JBAS010922: Starting server server-three
12:01:08,612 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process.Server:server-three.status] (ProcessController-threads - 6) JBAS012017: Starting process 'Server:server-three'
[Server:server-three] 12:01:10,708 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
[Server:server-three] 12:01:12,064 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
[Server:server-three] 12:01:12,293 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
[Server:server-three] 12:01:12,612 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
[Server:server-three] 12:01:12,635 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
[Server:server-three] 12:01:12,668 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
[Server:server-three] 12:01:16,176 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
[Server:server-three] 12:01:16,257 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 43) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
[Server:server-three] 12:01:16,325 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
[Server:server-three] 12:01:16,307 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
[Server:server-three] 12:01:16,498 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
[Server:server-three] 12:01:16,574 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
[Server:server-three] 12:01:16,574 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
[Server:server-three] 12:01:16,564 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) JBAS016300: Activating JacORB Subsystem
[Server:server-three] 12:01:16,532 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
[Host Controller] 12:01:16,744 INFO  [org.jboss.as.domain.controller.mgmt] (proxy-threads - 4) JBAS010920: Server [Server:server-three] registered using connection [Channel ID 6a098b8c (inbound) of Remoting connection 02ed01c3 to /192.168.100.105:58266]
[Server:server-three] 12:01:16,764 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) JBAS010260: Activating JGroups subsystem.
[Server:server-three] 12:01:16,926 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
[Host Controller] 12:01:17,056 INFO  [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (proxy-threads - 4) JBAS010919: Registering server server-three
[Server:server-three] 12:01:18,294 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
[Server:server-three] 12:01:18,297 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
[Server:server-three] 12:01:19,422 INFO  [org.jboss.jaxr] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS014000: Started JAXR subsystem, binding JAXR connection factory into JNDI as: java:jboss/jaxr/ConnectionFactory
[Server:server-three] 12:01:19,982 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be pasivated.
[Server:server-three] 12:01:20,078 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be pasivated.
[Server:server-three] 12:01:20,100 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
[Server:server-three] 12:01:20,698 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
[Server:server-three] 12:01:21,214 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-2) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--192.168.100.105-8330
[Server:server-three] 12:01:21,297 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol] (MSC service thread 1-2) Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp--192.168.100.105-8259
[Server:server-three] 12:01:21,670 INFO  [org.jboss.modcluster.ModClusterService] (MSC service thread 1-2) Initializing mod_cluster 1.2.0.Final
[Server:server-three] 12:01:21,797 INFO  [org.jboss.modcluster.advertise.impl.AdvertiseListenerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-2) Listening to proxy advertisements on 224.0.1.105:23364
[Server:server-three] 12:01:23,012 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100: Listening on /192.168.100.105:4697
[Server:server-three] 12:01:23,019 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
[Server:server-three] 12:01:24,535 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
[Server:server-three] JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
[Server:server-three]       service jboss.binding.jacorb (missing) dependents: [service jboss.jacorb.orb-service]
[Server:server-three]       service jboss.binding.jacorb-ssl (missing) dependents: [service jboss.jacorb.orb-service]
[Server:server-three]       service jboss.binding.messaging (missing) dependents: [service jboss.messaging.default]
[Server:server-three]       service jboss.binding.messaging-throughput (missing) dependents: [service jboss.messaging.default]
[Server:server-three]
[Server:server-three] 12:01:24,545 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 15375ms - Started 146 of 280 services (12 services failed or missing dependencies, 121 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Any help on the 4 missing items?

Comment: I have figured it out.
Ok.
JBoss 7.1.1 has "server-three" in the "full-ha" profile.

In "domain/configuration/domain.xml" the socket is bound to "ha-sockets".
if you change it from "ha-sockets" to "full-ha-sockets" then everything works out nicely.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out. Ok. JBoss 7.1.1 has "server-three" in the "full-ha" profile. In "domain/configuration/domain.xml" the socket is bound to "ha-sockets". if you change it from "ha-sockets" to "full-ha-sockets" then everything works out nicely. Thank you.